# Is it possible to run transaction mon local mongod v4.2.8

Tags: mongodb, go, transactions

When trying to run transaction on remove (Go):

```
func (dal *DAL) GetAndRemoveOneCode() (string, error) {

    var session mongo.Session
    var err error
    var ctx = context.Background()
    var result *mongo.DeleteResult
    var codeContainer models.CodeContainer
    var cursor *mongo.Cursor

    for result == nil || result.DeletedCount != 1 {
        var batchSize int32 = 1
        pipeline := mongo.Pipeline{bson.D{{Key: "$sample", Value: bson.D{{Key: "size", Value: 1}}}}}
        cursor, err = dal.mongodb.GetDatabase().Collection(collectionName).Aggregate(ctx, pipeline, &options.AggregateOptions{BatchSize: &batchSize})
        if err != nil {
            return "", err
        }

        for cursor.Next(ctx) {
            // decode the document
            if err := cursor.Decode(&codeContainer); err != nil {
                return "", err
            }
        }

        if session, err = dal.mongodb.GetDatabase().Client().StartSession(); err != nil {
            return "", err
        }
        if err = session.StartTransaction(); err != nil {
            return "", err
        }
        if err = mongo.WithSession(ctx, session, func(sc mongo.SessionContext) error {
            if result, err = dal.mongodb.GetDatabase().Collection(collectionName).DeleteOne(sc, bson.D{{Key: "_id", Value: codeContainer.ID}}); err != nil {
                return err
            }
            if result.DeletedCount != 1 {
                return err
            }

            if err = session.CommitTransaction(sc); err != nil {
                return err
            }
            return nil
        }); err != nil {
            return "", err
        }
        session.EndSession(ctx)
    }

    return codeContainer.Code, nil
}
```

I am getting the following (only in local, even after updating (version verified via mongod --version)):

> ERROR:
> Code: Unknown
> Message: (IllegalOperation) Transaction numbers are only allowed on a replica set member or mongos

- It works on Atlas, so it's only a local related issue

So my question is:

**Is it possible to run transaction mon local mongod v4.2.8**

Thanks

Comment: You need to run a replica set, but you can run a single-node replica set for development purposes.

Comment: Hi! Thanks but how do you achieve this please?

Comment: You should also use the withTransaction api if it is implemented by the go driver. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/

Comment: You follow instructions for creating a replica set but only configure one node instead of 3.